# Archimate study guide needed

Tags: architecture, archimate

Does any one have any suggestion to learn Archimate?
I need some study guide.
I used a book called "Enterprise architecture at work" but I gave up on fifth part named "Language for Enterprise Modelling" it was very vague to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You need the book "Mastering ArchiMate" by Gerben Wierda - https://ea.rna.nl/the-book-edition-iii/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your question is still valid but there is a book called "Archimate in practice" or in Dutch "Archimate in de praktijk" which suits your question.

Answer (score 1):

**ArchiMate Self Study Pack**

This bundle is for individuals wishing to self-study for ArchiMate 2 Certification and who plan to take the ArchiMate 2 examinations.
It includes the following materials in a single bundle:

```
ArchiMate® 2 Certification Study Guide (PDF), which includes the ArchiMate 2 Part 1 and Part 2 Examination Practice Tests
ArchiMate® 2.1 Reference Card (PDF)
ArchiMate® 2.1 Viewpoints Reference Card (PDF)
ArchiMate® 2.1 Metamodels Reference Card (PDF)
ArchiMate® 2.1 Summary Reference Card (PDF)
ArchiMate 2.1 Pocket Guide (PDF)
```

In addition it also contains the following bonus material:

```
Case Study: ArchiSurance Case Study (PDF)
Information Sheets on the ArchiMate 2 Certification Program (PDF)
Advice to Candidates Sheet for those attending a Prometric test center
White Paper: An introduction to ArchiMate 2.0
White Paper: ArchiMate 2.0 – Understanding the Basics
White Paper: Why Enterprise Architecture Matters
Slide Decks: An Introduction to the ArchiMate 2 for People Certification Program
Slide Decks: An Introduction to ArchiMate 2
ArchiMate 2.1 Visio Stencil Set
```

[**ArchiMate Self Study Pack**](https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/catalog/B132)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you learn about ArchiMate by studying the resources below.

- [Official ArchiMate 3.0.1 specification by the Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/archimate3-doc/). This is the official ArchiMate specification written by the Open Group. It details everything related to the ArchiMate Enterprise Architecture modeling language, such as the notations, semantics, relationships, viewpoints, etc.
- [Book - Mastering ArchiMate Edition III](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9081984098). The is one of the most popular books that talks about ArchiMate. It gives an introduction to the ArchiMate language as well as to show you key aspects of successful enterprise modeling, along with many different patterns for practical use. Although the aim of the book is to teach the language, it also provides necessary background, making it suitable for readers with levels of knowledge (even if you are not familiar with the language). Besides ArchiMate, also covers subjects like virtualization, bitcoin/blockchain, BPMN, infrastructure as code, processes versus functions, SOA/API, ESB, Terminal Services, etc.
- [Guide - Full ArchiMate Viewpoints Guide (Examples Included)](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/archimate/full-archimate-viewpoints-guide/). Viewpoints is an important concept in ArchiMate. A viewpoint contains a dedicated set of ArchiMate elements that allows architect designers to model a specific aspect of an enterprise architecture. The official ArchiMate 3 specification provides 23 ArchiMate example viewpoints for architecture designers to follow. This ArchiMate viewpoints guide goes over all these 23 ArchiMate viewpoints, with clear description and ArchiMate diagram examples for each of them.
- [Article - What's New in ArchiMate 3?](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/archimate/whats-new-in-archimate-3/) This article provides an overview of the ArchiMate 3.0 Specification which is a major update to the ArchiMate 2.1 Specification and was published as an Open Group Standard in June 2016.
- [Article - What is ArchiMate?](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/archimate/what-is-archimate/) This article introduces ArchiMate , an independent modelling language for enterprise architecture, invented by the Open Group.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may reference to the resource page below which covering different resources on ArchiMate, including notations reference, explanation of different layers as well as examples.

https://archimate.visual-paradigm.com/category/what-is-archimate/

Answer (score 0):

Also you can just use the archimate documentation http://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/archimate2-doc/toc.html